# Memory leak in spring boot embedded in-memory h2db

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

[Mat heapdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKPPP.jpg)I am using Spring boot In-Memory H2DB. I am storing latest 100k records in the database, so  keep on deleting old records and inserting new records. Application runs fine for 4-5 hours, after that it throws OOM Exception. The memory consumption keeps on increasing even after deleting old records.
I took the thread dump and analysed in MAT, it shows one memory leak.

`One instance of org.h2.mvstore.tx.TransactionStore$TxMapBuilder$TMVMap loaded by org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x6c0737918 occupies 2,08,58,61,856 (77.95%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of org.h2.mvstore.Page$PageReference[], loaded by org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x6c0737918, which occupies 2,08,58,61,384 (77.95%) bytes.`

When I restart the application with same number of records in H2db, it takes only  30% of  memory.

**H2db Version**: 2.1.212

**Spring boot**: 2.7.1

**Spring data JPA**:2.7.1

**spring.datasource.url**=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;

I tried with few other configuration of h2 db like QUERY_CACHE_SIZE=0, but same problem.
The expectation is , memory should get released after deleting the records from h2 db, but not the case.

Comment: have you tried increasing JVM heap? configured H2 to use disk storage? checked all connections are closed? used profiler to identify the source of the memory leak?

Comment: Yes, I tried with 3G,4G and 5G heap size. my requirement is to use in-memory database. The profiler points to org.h2.mvstore.Page$PageReference as memory leak.

Comment: If you store binary objects, an excessive use of ram is expected

Answer (score 0):

We run into similar problem in prod recently and it seems it is the bug in H2 when in-memory storage is used.
Please check issue https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3633
There is no release yet containing fix, but in another (duplicate https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3652) issue it is suggested to
"add ;MAX_LENGTH_INPLACE_LOB=2000000000 to JDBC URL as a temporary workaround."
We are in process of checking this workaround so no confirmation yet is available, but worth a try.

Comment: To give more background: we use LOBs stored in-memory (the take much space as they are pdf documents). We increased application heap size from 7GB to 9GB only to hit the ceiling (OOM) a little bit later than previously.